# How result handler should be treated in a situation where we have nested loop + vert.x + rx

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, vert.x

I have three methods

1) Get Template

2) Get Field (template id)

3) Get Field Metadata (field id)

The order of the methods calling is from top to bottom. The getTemplate() method returns single template. Based on the response I call my second method to get the fields associated to it. I get multiple fields against a template. I loop through the fields and look for fields metadata. Each field has a metadata.

The problem I am facing is, my method return one template and one filed only. I does not loop through the other fields. The reason I can see is the way I am handling handler. What is the best way to handle the handler when we have nested loop situation.

Here is my code,

First Method

```
 public Single<Template> getByName(String lookupName) {
        return new AsyncResultSingle<Template>(resultHandler -> {
            jdbcClient.rxGetConnection().subscribe(connection -> {
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM template t WHERE t.name=?";
                JsonArray params = new JsonArray().add(lookupName);

                connection.rxQueryWithParams(sql, params).subscribe(resultSet -> {
                    List<JsonObject> rows = resultSet.getRows();
                    Template template = new Template();

                    for (JsonObject jsonObject : rows) {
                        template.id = jsonObject.getInteger("id");
                        template.name = jsonObject.getString("name", "");
                        template.column = jsonObject.getInteger("columns", -1);

                        Single<Map<Integer, TemplateField>> rxFields = templateFieldDao.getAllFields(template);
                        rxFields.subscribe(fields -> {
                            template.fields = fields; 
                             resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(template));  
                        }, failure -> {
                            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(failure));
                        });            
                    }

                }, onError -> {
                    resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(onError));
                });
            }, onError -> {
                resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(onError));
            });
        });
    }
```

Second Method

```
 public Single<Map<Integer, TemplateField>> getAllFields(Template template) {

        return new AsyncResultSingle<Map<Integer, TemplateField>>(resultHandler -> {
            jdbcClient.rxGetConnection().subscribe(connection -> {
                String sql = "SELECT * from template_field as f where f.template_id=?";
                JsonArray params = new JsonArray().add(template.id);

                connection.rxQueryWithParams(sql, params).subscribe(resultSet -> {
                    Map<Integer, TemplateField> templateFieldMap = new HashMap<Integer, TemplateField>();
                    List<JsonObject> rows = resultSet.getRows();

                    for (JsonObject jsonObject : rows) {
                        TemplateField templateField = new TemplateField();   
                        templateField.id = jsonObject.getInteger("id");
                        templateField.name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        templateField.order = jsonObject.getInteger("sort_order");
                        templateField.column_id = jsonObject.getInteger("column_id");
                        templateField.template_id = jsonObject.getInteger("template_id");

                        Single<Map<Integer, Metadata>> rxMetaData = metadata.getByFieldId(templateField);
                        rxMetaData.subscribe(fieldMetadata -> {
                            templateField.metadata = fieldMetadata;
                            templateFieldMap.put(templateField.id, templateField);
                             resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(templateFieldMap));
                        }, failure -> {
                            resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(failure));
                        });
                    }

                }, onError -> {
                    resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(onError));
                });
            }, onError -> {
                resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(onError));
            });
        });

    }
```

Third Method

```
public Single<Map<Integer, Metadata>> getByFieldId(TemplateField field) {
        return new AsyncResultSingle<Map<Integer, Metadata>>(resultHandler -> {
            jdbcClient.rxGetConnection().subscribe(connection -> {
                String sql = "SELECT m.id as id, m.name as name, m.value as value, m.isProperty as isValue FROM template_field_metadata as m WHERE m.template_field_id=?";
                JsonArray params = new JsonArray().add(field.id);
                Map<Integer, Metadata> metadataMap = new HashMap<Integer, Metadata>();

                connection.rxQueryWithParams(sql, params).subscribe(resultSet -> {
                    List<JsonObject> rows = resultSet.getRows();

                    for (JsonObject object : rows) {
                        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                        metadata.id = object.getInteger("id");
                        metadata.name = object.getString("name");
                        metadata.value = object.getString("value"); 
                        metadata.isValue = object.getBoolean("isValue"); 
                        metadataMap.put(metadata.id, metadata);
                    }

                    resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(metadataMap));
                }, onError -> {
                    resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(onError));
                });
            }, onError -> {
                resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(onError));
            });
        });
```

I think the time I send the Future.succeeded() back. My program considered the request has been completed. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

I have posted this question on vertx dev google group. Let us see if anybody respond [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/vertx/n1RhpuP2XGY).

Answer (score 0):

When working with rx you should avoid subscribing multiple times because once you subscribe the stream ends and you are forced to handle the onError and OnSucess handlers.  The responsibility for handling that should be on the caller.

The way I think of rx is that you a working with a stream of logic where each step in the synchronous logic will yield results used by the next operation in the stream.

So from my understanding of the code provided in the first the example you want to query for the templates by name and then query for the remaining fields from a separate DAO object and send them to the caller.

See the following code (I've provided some comments explaining it let me know if you need more explanation):

```
public Single<List<Template>> getByName(String lookupName) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM template t WHERE t.name=?";
        JsonArray params = new JsonArray().add(lookupName);

        return jdbcClient.rxGetConnection()
        //you use flatmap to tranform a yield a observable
        .flatMap(connection ->  connection.rxQueryWithParams(sql, params))
        //you use a map when you need to transform a value into another value
        .map(resultSet -> resultSet.getRows()) //if this is supposed to only return one result you'll have have to throw an error
        .toObservable() //we need to say this if we plan on having multiple values
        .flatMap(Observable::from)//this would take the rows from the result set and convert it into an stream of json objects
        .flatMap(jsonObject -> {
            Template template = new Template();
            template.id = jsonObject.getInteger("id");
            template.name = jsonObject.getString("name", "");
            template.column = jsonObject.getInteger("columns", -1);
            return template
        })
        .flatMap(template -> templateFieldDao.getAllFields(template).toObservable())//It looks like your dao is yielding a single so we want observables until the next step
        .toList()//returns Single<List<Template>>
    }
```

So the caller of this method will be the one to subscribe and handle the values. I noticed a small problem with you example where you could complete an future multiple times which would cause unexpected behavior because you were expecting to yield a Single.  A Single is either a one value or error.  If you need to return multiple values you should use something like Observable or combine everything into a list as I'm doing above.

As a bonus when writing unit tests with rx I've found that converting the lambda functions to method references makes the code a lot easier to unit test!  It will save you some time later :)

For your other two examples if you follow this same pattern you should be good to go!

Let me know if you have any questions!!

Comment: I got the idea. This is clear that I can use .map to transform a value to another value and .flatMap to to produce an observable or chain another asynchronous action. The thing which is not clear to me so far is, how I should manage to set the resultHandler in a situation where I have loop. Like in my example I could have list of fields and each filed could have multiple metadata. In synchronous programming I normally get the list of fields and loop through on fields and pull the relevant field metadata. I have tried the same way but I am stuck on where I consider my resultHandler succeeded.